# Cursor reset after key input - Vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

```
nmap <F9> gg=G
imap <F9> <ESC>gg=Ga
```

I have this in my `.vimrc`, I'm in the middle of my source file and this lines works as expected which means that what is defined in `equalprg` is executed correctly, the problem is that after this execution my cursor returns at the top of the file which is something that I really don't want to happen: there is a way to avoid that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set and return to a *mark* (e.g. `a`):

```
nmap <F9> magg=Gg`a
```

Comment: my only problem now, to reach the perfection, I would like to re-enter the insert-mode with the `imap` mapping, how to modify my settings for that ?

Comment: wait a minute, the cursor is 1 step before the previous position in my terminal, it's not really at the original position.

Comment: The `imap` is analog; the exact position may not be reached, because Vim cannot account for what the `=` command does.

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap <f9> gg=G``
```

``` `` ``` will jump back to the spot before the last jump.

```
:h ``
```